# How to check if alternate letters are similar in a string using RegEx Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to solve a problem using Regex Python3.

For instance, Given a string, I want to check each character in the string and return true if any character has the same left, and right characters (e.g. "454", "aba")

Input : `a = "4346789"`

Output: `"True"`           (because character sits in left and right of '3' are same ie '4')

---

Input2: `a = "4335667"`

Output: `"False"`.         (because there is no character that is same to left and right of each character)

How can I write a Regex to determine if the characters to the left and right of each character are the same?

Comment: Yes, Only through RegEx

Comment: What about 1437642? does that pass (it has 4 in 2nd and 6th index)?

Comment: Or 1333567? Is the number allowed to be in consecutive indexes as well?

Comment: Can you add more examples please?

Comment: consecutive is fine. Only alternate numbers shouldn't be similar. 1437642 and 1333567 are valid.

Comment: 1456500 - Invalid because of alternate 5s.
121788- Invalid because of alternate 1s.
3344565 - Invalid because of alternate 5s. 
1223344 - Valid as there are no alternate similar numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:

https://regex101.com/r/W7SAZU/1

The regex is :

```
'(.).\1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked fine for me, hope it finds its way to other souls in need

```
def alternate(s: str):

    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        if i > 0:
            if i > 1 and v == s[i-1]:
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The second solution doesn't work for me but this code works

```
def twoalter( s):
    for i in range ( len( s) - 2) :
        if (s[i] != s[i + 2]) :
            return False
    if (s[0] == s[1]):
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked on Python 3.7.3:

```
import re

def hasAlternate(str):
    p = re.compile('(.).\\1')
    m = p.search(str) is not None
    return m

print(hasAlternate('4346789'))
print(hasAlternate('4335667'))
```

Comment: This works only if there are same alternate characters in 1st and 3rd index of the string. we have to check all indexes and make sure no alternate indexes are same. 
For e.g "122343" will return False with above code, but its expected to return True.

Comment: @RAMMURTY Thank you for your advice. I updated p.match to p.search.

Comment: This should be (.).\1

Comment: @RAMMURTY Take a look at:
Raw String Notation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation

or try it:
https://ideone.com/uAPBwn